# Javascript and CSS not working after uploading the website online but they are working fine locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, namecheap

Here is the site in question  http://www.rfindings.net/
I have uploaded the code to github - https://github.com/Shaivik7/rfindings

Now the home page has 2 images that should be switching every 4 secs which is not happening online but working fine offline.
If you see any missing semicolons I have fixed them and tried again but nothing changes.

And for CSS part I have wrote the media query according to resized browser but the site looks completely different on mobile, I used media query for anything less than 768px but still on mobile it looks completely different.

I am beginner so I hope my code isn't too messy if it is I apologize in advance.
I am hosting this site at namecheap
If you have to time please take a look.. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have meta tag added in head for responsive to work. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Yes I have added it

Comment: it's a simple mistake. you compare image url with some file at your C drive, which doesn't work online.

Comment: Oh yeah! Wow Thank you.. But now what should I do can you nudge me in some direction regarding the same? How can I replace this part of code?